# Make Sonarqube Github plugin mark the PR with failure even for issues with severity lower than Critical

Tags: github, sonarqube

I managed to make SonarCloud inspect internal pull requests and write comments on each line where issues are found (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/#Activation-for-internal-pull-requests).

The Sonarqube Github plugin (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) makes the PR fail if there's a critical or blocker issue:

> if no blocker no critical issues were found, the check is green -
>   otherwise it is red to raise attention.

I'd like to make the check red even for issues with lower severity (e.g., "major") but I found no setting...

is that possible at all?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the GitHub Plugin does not have such feature.

Comment: and if I understand correctly from here https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/pull/28 it won't even ever have that...